How to write the long query statement in Apache IoTDB to be in multiple lines?
My name settings in the m-tree data structure in Apache IoTDB is relatively long, and the hierarchy is in many layers. Therefore, my query statement used in IoTDB may be long, so I want to ask can the query statement in IoTDB be written in multiple lines? If it can be written in this way, how should I use the newline character?

You can add line breaks in the middle of sql statements in Apache IoTDB, and there's no definite limits on the length of sql statements, so the long name you have can be successfully written. However, remember not to add line breaks in a single keyword (for example function name).
